# PHP simple foreach loop doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

I'm trying to do an easy `foreach` loop, but it print out only one row, instead of the two rows in db (I've tried to put other rows in db but got only the first one, I can't find the error.

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    $sql = "SELECT flyer_url FROM films LIMIT 30";

    $films = $dbh->query($sql);

    $result = $films->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($result as $row) {

        print "<img src='" . $row . "' style='width:200px;'>" ;

    }

    $dbh = null;
}
catch (PDOexception $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e-> etmessage() . '<br/>Contact the System Administrator.';
}
```

Suppose the DB conf data are in config.php and it's loaded successfully.

I'm trying to create a personal film DB and show the playbill of each film.

Comment: I think u need to use fetchAll instead of fetch : http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) returns **a single row**, in your case - represented as an associative array. In order to get all the rows, you'd have to continue iterating over `fetch`'s results:

```
while($row = $films->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    print "<img src='" . $row['flyer_url'] . "' style='width:200px;'>" ;
}
```

Comment: isn't fetchAll faster because it does one database query with respect to fetch in every iteration?

Comment: @Melvin `fetchAll` is a terrible function. With `fetch` you allow PDO to control how many rows it brings to its internal buffer at a time. `fetchAll` forces PDO to bring all of them at once, possibly crashing your application since it takes too much memory.

Comment: @Melvin also note that even with `fetch` it's still a single query - just with multiple fetches. The main strain on the network is passing the query's result data. Breaking it to several smaller fetches should be relatively negligible, except for some very specific edge cases.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
$result = $films->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

to

```
$result = $films->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do like this-

```
$data="";
foreach($result as $row) { 
$data .= "<img src='" . $row['flyer_url'] . "' style='width:200px;'>" ; 
}
```

This will concatenate string and will give you combine result outside foreach loop.

Comment: Not suitable for pdo database interaction .will work only for core mysql handling .